# Swift Chain Closure

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I wanna create chain closure for response of alamofire request.

I have a class like that:

```
 class Login {

        static let shared = Login()

        func getGuestToken() {

            Alamofire.request(AlamoRouter.Token()).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TokenModel>) in
                let errorMessage = "General error"
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    let token = response.result.value

                case .failure(_):
                    if let data = response.data {
                        let responseData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                        print(responseData ?? "test")
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

In a viewController class, i wanna make request like that:

Login.shared.getGuestToken().onSuccess { model in }.onError{ error . in }

How can i do that? I tried to many way (like that https://owensd.io/2015/02/20/handling-multiple-closure-parameters/) but it did not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to use `Login.shared.getGuestToken()?.onSuccess { model in }?.onError{ error . in }`:

```
protocol ErrorProtocol {
    func onError(completion: (Error?) -> ())
}

protocol SuccessProtocol {
    func onSuccess(completion: (String?) -> ()) -> ErrorProtocol?
}

class Test: SuccessProtocol, ErrorProtocol {
    var model: String?
    var error: Error?

    required init(model: String?, error: Error?) {
        self.model = model
        self.error = error
    }

    func onSuccess(completion: (String?) -> ()) -> ErrorProtocol? {
        if model != nil {
            completion(model)
        }
        return self
    }

    func onError(completion: (Error?) -> ()) {
        completion(error)
    }
}

class Login {

    static let shared = Login()

    func getGuestToken() -> SuccessProtocol? {

        var test: Test?
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        Alamofire.request(AlamoRouter.Token()).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TokenModel>) in
            let errorMessage = "General error"
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                let token = response.result.value
                test = Test(model: token, error: nil)

            case .failure(error):
                if let data = response.data {
                    let responseData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print(responseData ?? "test")
                    test = Test(model: nil, error: error)
                }
            }
            semaphore.signal()
        }

        _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
        return test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your method as

```
class Login {

    static let shared = Login()

    func getGuestToken(onSuccess : ((String) -> ()), onError: ((Error) -> ())) {

        Alamofire.request(AlamoRouter.Token()).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TokenModel>) in
            let errorMessage = "General error"
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                let token = response.result.value
                onSuccess(token)

            case .failure(error):
                if let data = response.data {
                    let responseData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print(responseData ?? "test")
                    onError(error)
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, i know that way but it is not supply that style calling: Login.shared.getGuestToken().onSuccess { model in }.onError{ error . in }

Comment: I have seen promise kit using similar syntax have a look at this https://www.raywenderlich.com/145683/getting-started-promises-promisekit

Comment: @SandeepBhandari - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538998/validate-the-phone-number-and-email-in-same-text-filed-in-objective-c/46544074#46544074) once, if any modification plz inform me